# Facebook: get OpenGraphStory reactions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve the reactions on an `open_graph_story`.

According to [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/open-graph-object--generic/reactions/), I should be able to just call:

```
{object-id}/reactions
```

So I first I got my `open_graph_story`'s id like this:

```
{page-id}/ratings?field=open_graph_story{id}
```

And then I tried the `reactions` endpoint like above, but I end up with this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (reactions) on node type (OpenGraphAction)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "some id"
  }
}
```

Apparently, the endpoint doesn't work with an `open_graph_story` (which is recognized as an OpenGraphAction by Facebook?).
What should be the correct call?